# An equilateral triangular pyramid from four equilateral triangles - Using Snap

Tags: snapping

An equilateral triangular pyramid from four equilateral triangles.

How to model this type of object using the snap function in Blender?

Please, share your expertise regarding this type of modeling. How to do that?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following solution is if you just want to get a tetrahedron object. To create one from scratch it's not so easy to do it with rotating and snapping, because you have to set the rotation axes correctly and let's say you have the base triangle and add another one to rotate upwards - there's nothing to snap to. You can just rotate it by be the correct angle of 70.53° and do the same with the others. But than there's no need to do it manually. For getting a regular tetrahedron easier do the following:

Go into the 3D Viewport to add a new object: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Mesh* > *Geodesic Dome*. There are different presets to choose from, the shape that comes by default is a tetrahedron, exactly what you want to create.

If you don't have *Geodesic Dome* as option in the *Mesh* menu, go into top menu *Edit* > *Preferences* > *Add-ons* and typ "geo" in the search field. Enable the add-on "Add Mesh: Geodesic Domes".

[image: geodesic dome]

[image: addon geodesic domes]